# Which password does Mist require when sending from the presale wallet?

Tags: mist, wallets, password, presale, recovery

Yesterday I was able to import my presale ether into my wallet and the balance now shows in the Ethereum Wallet.  However, whenever I try to send and it asks for my password, it says "wrong password".  How can I resolve this issue? I've restarted the computer with no luck, and I've tried all the passwords I can imagine, including the one for the presale wallet.

I've since tried to deposit into Kraken with https://www.kraken.com/ether/ and getting "Deposit failed: Invalid sender" after hitting "Deposit to Kraken". I imagine that is because the ether is now in my wallet and not in the json file, right?

Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks.